# Adding routing in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a requirement in which I have to map the below url

```
/amer/us/en/ = Home controller
/amer/us/en/login/index = Home controller
/amer/us/en/confirmation = Confirmation controller
```

along with the regular default action.

Eg if user goes to

```
http:\\test.com --> http://test/home/index
 http:\\test.com/amer/us/en/login/index  --> http://test/home/index
 http:\\test.com/amer/us/en/   --> http://test/home/index
```

I was looking into attribute routing and so I added the below code in HomeController

```
  [RoutePrefix("amer/us/en/")]
    [Route("{action=index}")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

    }
```

and I am getting this error
`The route prefix 'amer/us/en/' on the controller named 'Home' cannot begin or end with a forward slash` and also the default routing is not working now so http://test.com is not loading anything. Below is my default RouteConfig class.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Very new to MVC. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routing in MVC works either by defining your routes in the `RouteConfig` class or by attribute routing (or you can use Areas). Routing with RouteConfig works with the order you define the routes with. When a request comes, MVC will try your routes from top to bottom and execute the first one that it can match with the requested url. So the routing need in your example can be achieved by:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RootLogin",
            url: "amer/us/en/login/index/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultAmer",
            url: "amer/us/en/{controller}/{action}{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ); 

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

this will map login as a special route and all the other `/amer/us/en/` routes will go to whatever `controller` comes after and whatever `action` of it. The last route, if the request does not start with `/amer/us/en` will perform the default behavior.

Looks like, however, you want to define `/amer/us/en/` as an Area, so you might want to take a look into that as well.

Comment: Works great..Thank u so much.